# How to save looping dictionary from beautifulsoup4 scraping result to JSON file format..?

Tags: python, json, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have scraping data from a website page using beautifulsoup4, and save the scraping result to a dictionary of list like this:

```
DATA = [
            TITLE, {
                'IMAGES': IMAGE,
                'URL_VIDEOS': URL_VIDEOS,
                'DESCRIPTIONS': DESCRIPTIONS,
                'SYNOPSIS': SYNOPSIS
            }
        ]
```

which is the values **IMAGE**, **URL_VIDOES**, **DESCRIPTIONS** AND **SYNOPSIS** are for the variable scraping result.

and I try save the variable data to a **.json** file extension with this code:

```
json_file = open('result.json', 'w')
json.dump(DATA, json_file)
json_file.close()
```

I got the result like this:

```
["Action Fruits", {"IMAGES": "http://animeindo.video/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/rsz_heroin.jpg", "URL_VIDEOS": "http://www.mp4upload.com/embed-q7xxgge1yu1c.html", "DESCRIPTIONS": {"Japanese": " \u30a2\u30af\u30b7\u30e7\u30f3\u30d2\u30ed\u30a4\u30f3 \u30c1\u30a2\u30d5\u30eb\u30fc\u30c4", "\nProducer": " Diomedea", "\nType": " TV Series", "\nStatus": " Ongoing", "\nGenre": " Comedy, School, Slice of Life", "\nDurasi": " 24 min", "\nEpisode": " \u2013", "\nRating": " 6.11", "\nAdded On": " July 12th, 2017"}, "SYNOPSIS": "Japanese: \u30a2\u30af\u30b7\u30e7\u30f3\u30d2\u30ed\u30a4\u30f3 \u30c1\u30a2\u30d5\u30eb\u30fc\u30c4\nProducer: Diomedea\nType: TV Series\nStatus: Ongoing\nGenre: Comedy, School, Slice of Life\nDurasi: 24 min\nEpisode: \u2013\nRating: 6.11\nAdded On: July 12th, 2017\nSinopsis:\nPerjuangan pahlawan lokal dalam menyelamatkan daerahnya.\n"}]
```

But over the looping in that scrape, the result in that **.json** file always be overwritten, that's not added the new data, just overwritten with the new data like this:

```
["Happy", {"IMAGES": "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-SUq5_dpoIlM/VwpKqqsEzNI/AAAAAAAAM50/H81MUyDLZA0ctj8zo8JbuUVPPz4sxQulw/s1600/77219__1460292250_36.80.228.117.jpg", "URL_VIDEOS": "http://www.mp4upload.com/embed-ptj9hmeefar8.html", "DESCRIPTIONS": {"Japanese": " \u3042\u3093\u30cf\u30d4\u266a", "\nProducer": " Silver Link", "\nType": " TV Series", "\nStatus": " Ongoing", "\nGenre": " Comedy, School, Slice of Life", "\nDurasi": " 23 min. per ep.", "\nEpisode": " 12", "\nRating": " 7.06", "\nAdded On": " April 10th, 2016"}, "SYNOPSIS": "Japanese: \u3042\u3093\u30cf\u30d4\u266a\nProducer: Silver Link\nType: TV Series\nStatus: Ongoing\nGenre: Comedy, School, Slice of Life\nDurasi: 23 min. per ep.\nEpisode: 12\nRating: 7.06\nAdded On: April 10th, 2016\nSinopsis:\nMenceritakan kelas 1-7 di Akademi Tennomifune, di mana semua murid yang suka sial berkumpul. Hibari, salah satu murid di kelas ini, bertemu dengan si sial Hanako di hari pertama sekolah, dan bersama-sama mereka berjuang mencari hidup bahagia di sekolah mereka.\n"}]
```

And the next result also overwritten...

I want to added new data, and save all of the result of scraping with one **.json** file. So.. how to do that..?

Answer (score 2):

`'w'` file mode would rewrite the file every time you write to it.

`'a'` would not work here as well as it would result into an invalid JSON file.

What you should do is to collect the results while you scrape (into a list?) and then dump into the JSON file once **after** you are done looping through the data.

Comment: Hey.. @alecxe, can you specify more details about it..?

Comment: @Tri well, sure, but for that I would need to see more of your code - especially the part where you are setting the `DATA` values.

Answer (score 1):

How you select `IMAGES` or `URL_VIDEOS` by `TITLE`? I think your json is not correct because Title is value not key, maybe it should be like this format

```
{
  "title A" : {"IMAGES" : "IMAGE A"},
  "title B" : {"IMAGES" : "IMAGE B"}
}
```

Or

```
[
  {"Title" : "title A", "IMAGES" : "IMAGE A"},
  {"Title" : "title B", "IMAGES" : "IMAGE B"}
]
```

Let try with first example, You need to read previous json and `update()` with new data, first make sure to delete `result.json`

```
import os.path

....
DATA = {"Action Fruits": {"IMAGES": "a.jpg", "URL_VIDEOS" : "http://a.mp4"}}

OLD_DATA = {} # set old data to this if file not exist
if os.path.isfile('result.json'):
    with open('result.json', 'r') as f:
        OLD_DATA = json.load(f)
        # {"Happy" : {"IMAGES" : "b.jpg", "URL_VIDEOS" : "http://b.mp4"}}

# concatenate old and new data
DATA.update(OLD_DATA)
with open('result.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(DATA, f)
```

**result.json**

```
{
  "Action Fruits": {"IMAGES": "a.jpg", "URL_VIDEOS": "http://a.mp4"}, 
  "Happy": {"IMAGES": "b.jpg", "URL_VIDEOS": "http://b.mp4"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by this following code:

```
 with open('result.json', 'a') as outfile:
      outfile.write(json.dumps(DATA, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444191/python-loop-overwrites-previous-text-written-to-json-file).

Comment: Are you sure you gonna end up with a *valid JSON* at the end?

Comment: ah.. I'm too early to happy, I look at the _JSON_ result again, and I got fews red highlight in my Pycharm